# Long text in a <td> div pushes icon to the next line. How do I stop this?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a div which is behaving badly. It seems that there is some very long text being put into a  div and it is causing the icon within the div to wrap to the next line.  How do I stop this maddening behavior?

```css
.itemStyle {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  height: 20px;
}

.SearchIconStyle {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 175px; overflow-y: auto; width: auto;">
  <table id="tblSelectedItem" runat="server">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class='itemStyle'>
            <div style='float: left; border: 0; min-width: 245px;'>&nbsp;</div>
            <div style='display: inline-block; float: left; border: 0;'>
              <img src="~/Images/search.png" id="imgSearch" alt="Select Items" runat="server" class="SearchIconStyle" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Click this link to displays the results of how this misbehaving div acts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwPnx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just 
align="top"     on both the text and the icon? may work

Comment: Hmmm...  Nope, I haven't tried that. Should I leave all the other stuff to like, "<div style='float: left; border: 0; min-width: 245px;'>&nbsp;</div>"?

Comment: Hmmm, on second thought, there does not appear to a choice for align: "top";    That does not appear to be a choice in asp.net/html5/css3.

Answer (score 0):

Use display: inline-block on both internal div's.

```html
<div style="max-height: 175px; overflow-y: auto; width: auto;">
  <table id="tblSelectedItem" runat="server">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div class='itemStyle'>
         <div style='display: inline-block; border: 0; min-width: 245px;'> 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789</div>
          <div style='display: inline-block; border: 0;'>
           <img src="~/Images/search.png" id="imgSearch" alt="Select Items" runat="server" class="SearchIconStyle" />
           </div>
          </div>
          </td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jerod, but that did not seem to do the trick. I have tried a number of things like text-overflow: ellipses, overflow: nowrap, etc.  All to no avail.

Comment: Did you remove the floats? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jhodgkin/4L4s14gy/)

Comment: Yes, thanks @Jerod. I believe that solved it, as well as well as, I believe, adding a break.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve this by removing the floats and changing some other supporting JavaScript, I believe..

Thanks all for your great suggestions. Have an awesome weekend!!